# complexType nodes with mixed="true" - How get the innerText and the node inside it - C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

For example:

```
<Inflection>innerText1</Inflection>
<Inflection>innerText2<Variant>innerText2Variant</Variant></Inflection>
```

We can get the innerText1 in C# by theNode.InnerText property but
how can we get the following info separately for the node in 2nd line?

- innerText2
- XmlNode of Variant
- innerText2Variant

Comment: Step 1, use [System.Xml.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netcore-3.0) and not some ancient, should be forgotten, part of .Net Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strXML = @"<root><Inflection>innerText1</Inflection>
                                <Inflection>innerText2<Variant>innerText2Variant</Variant></Inflection></root>";

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        xml.LoadXml(strXML);

        XmlNodeList nodesInflection = xml.SelectNodes("/root/Inflection");

        foreach(XmlNode n in nodesInflection)
        {
            if (n.ChildNodes.Count == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);

                //or 
                Console.WriteLine(n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);

                XmlNode nodeVariant = n.SelectSingleNode("Variant");

                //or
                //XmlNode nodeVariant = n.ChildNodes[1];


                Console.WriteLine(nodeVariant.InnerText);

            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*******press any key");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```